# Yet another syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, awk, printf, shebang, syntax

This one different from the others as:

1. I'm invoking bash (not sh) in the shebang: `#! /bin/bash`
2. I'm running it with `./`
3. File permissions are correct: `755`

The line in question is:

```
 formattedTIME=`awk '{printf("Duration:\t%02dh %02dm",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}' $domPATH/duration.seconds`
```

The content of `$domPATH/duration.seconds` is `37603`

I can run this at the command line:

```
formattedTIME=`awk '{printf("Duration:\t%02dh %02dm",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}' duration.seconds`
```

and get the result of `Duration: 10h 26m` when I `echo $formattedTIME`

But running it in in the script results in:

```
./time.sh: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./time.sh: line 42: `    formattedTIME=`awk '{printf("Duration:\t%02dh %02dm",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}' $domPATH/duration.seconds`'
```

Extra info:
This is on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Jessie.

UPDATE: The error was online 8:

```
echo 'Cc: xxx@xxxx.xxx,xxx@xxxx.xxx,xxx@xxxx.xxx,xxx@xxxx.xxx'' >> $domPATH/arrive.email
```

Comment: Works fine when I run it. Can you try to reduce the script to the minimal that is required to exhibit the problem, then post the whole script? I get the feeling you're probably forgetting to close something (perhaps `?) on a line above

Comment: It works fine for me, I can only think that the error is somewhere else in your script.

Comment: Possibly you have some unclosed `'...'` further up in the script, so the first `'` on that line closes it, and the next `(` after that causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, @StéphaneChazelas you hit the nail on the head. there was a triple `'` on line 8. (Found it while editing the question to include the full script here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few common trends on why a command doesn't parse properly in a script but is fine when run on its own:

### The source of the error is elsewhere

The shell will report an error on the first thing it doesn't expect. Here, it doesn't expect a `(`, yet it appears it's within a quoted string. A possible explanation is that you're not in a quoted string because the first `'` there actually closes an earlier unclosed quote instead of opening a new `'...'` on like in:

```
echo It's a bug
formattedTIME=`awk '{printf("Duration:\t%02dh %02dm",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}' $domPATH/duration.seconds
```

That's actually:

```
echo It'quoted-string'{printf("Duration:\t%02dh %02dm",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60))}'...
```

And that unquoted `(` above is unexpected by the shell.

You get similar problems with any structure that is not properly closed or in the wrong format, like a `fi` without a `then`...

### Backticks

Backticks should really not be used. `$(...)` should be used instead.

Inside backticks, `\` is handled differently.

```
echo "`
  echo It\\\'s OK
`"
```

is not OK. Even though `echo It\\\'s OK` by itself is OK, as inside backticks, the first two backslashes become one, so it ends up being `echo It\\'OK`.

The `$(...)` modern form doesn't have those problems.

### Aliases

aliases are a bit like macros, their expansion undergoes code interpretation again.

Things like:

```
alias foo="echo '"
...
foo bar
echo 'baz('
```

would have the problem hidden in the definition of the `foo` alias.

There are more subtle ones like:

```
alias foo='a;b'
cmd | foo
```

Which without causing syntax errors, cause the parsing to be done in an unexpected way.

Often, functions are more appropriate than aliases

### localisation

Some byte sequences can be interpreted differently depending on the locale.

For instance, the 0xa0 byte is the non-breaking space in the ISO-8859-1 character set. And that character happens to be a blank on Solaris, and `bash` happens to treat all blanks as delimiters (currently only for single-byte characters).

That 0xa0 byte  also happens  to be part of several UTF-8 characters like `à`. So you may find that for instance that a script that has:

```
var=àdo
```

(with that `à` written in UTF-8) stops working when run on Solaris in a ISO-8859-1 locale, because that becomes `var=X do` (where `X` is the first byte of that `à` character).

Or you may find that:

```
echo ε
```

With that `ε` written in the BIG5-HKSCS character set stops working when you're not in the `zh_HK.big5hkscs` locale, as that `ε` is actually encoded as 0xa3 0x60, where 0x60 in ASCII and all single-byte character sets is the backtick character.